# How to use Triggering and template to send sms

Tags: python, django

```
class CMSSmsTemplate(models.Model):
"""
This is the   internal template
Which will have the SMS Trigger field/the SmS body/the SmS Template
"""
  sms_trigger = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  sms_body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  sms_Body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  sms_template_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I have this model, which i'm using to send my sms, what triggers my sms to be sent is mainly the sms_template_name, how can i efficiently use,to trigger and send the sms. Any advices?

Comment: Not advisable to keep null=True for CharField and TextField.

Comment: Thanks, i will correct this ...

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Django signals(post_save) with celery in order trigger the SMS sending process when a new object is created I think it is the most efficient way to use. for easy implementation you can just use the post_save signal in order to trigger the SMS sending process please refer [this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-celery-with-django-for-background-task-processing--cms-28732)

Comment: Thank you, this might be useful.